# comparing 2 csv files using ansible

Tags: ansible

has anybody compare 2 csv files in ansible. can you provide an example code if so? 
I want to compare specific columns in csv files and output the differences to other file. I was able to easily do it using a powershell, looking to do it directly using ansible.

Answer (score 1):

There is a csvfile module in ansible that can read the content of csv file separated by comma. You can use two variables to store the column content and compare the two stored variables and find the difference and re direct to a file

Comment: Thanks. i am trying this